# Is Fid score script correct if I used batchsize as 1

Tags: tensorflow

Is the FID score works correctly in `tensorflow > 1.5` i.e if I run it with batch size 1?
I am using implementation of FID from https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR where there's an issue that it only runs with a batch size of 1.

I am running out of time, so I cannot write a script for implementing FID, therefore, can anyone confirm whether it gives correct value or not if I run with a batch size of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the script from [TTUR implementation](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR/tree/16150b2f1ce217c7def60b9b7c1cd180fb6d476c#provided-code) that calculates the FID score will work with any batch size value.
But note that they load all the images into the memory for this.

The mean and covariance matrix calculated for the FID score are defined over the activations of all the images. But to get the activations values we need to load the inception model and get those activations considering the amount of images defined by the batch size.

Those activations are calculated and accumulated by the function `get_activations` ([link](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR/blob/16150b2f1ce217c7def60b9b7c1cd180fb6d476c/fid.py#L67))

```
def get_activations(images, sess, batch_size=50, verbose=False):
   """Calculates the activations of the pool_3 layer for all images.
   ...
```

which are used to calculate the activation statistics (mean and covariance) with the function `calculate_activation_statistics` ([link](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR/blob/16150b2f1ce217c7def60b9b7c1cd180fb6d476c/fid.py#L159)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I am having a confusion in way of computing FID scores for celebA dataset. At official repository, one way is to pass pre-computed statistics file along with generated samples directory path (say Method M1).Other way is to pass path of directories containing samples of original & generated images(Method M2). For training I have resized original images to 64x64 whereas [statistics file](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR) is for original image size.By method M1, FID should be wrong because it compares against statistics for original images which has size greater than size of generated images.

Comment: I think the correct is M2. You should compute the FID score with real (set A) and generated images (set B) of the same size. In this way, you will be considering the same pixel dimensionality for both A and B. But note: TTUR feed the images to layer ExpandDims:0 of the Incep. Model(IM), which resizes the image to the requested size of IM. Thus, if you resize the images to 64x64, later on your images will be resized to the original image size of IM. Although you will add one resize operation with method M2, you will apply the same transformations for both A and B, which will not happen with M1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was not aware of the fact that the IM(Inception Model) resize the images implicitly in process of evaluating FID score.